# Webview security on 3D Secure payments on Android

Tags: android, android-webview, 3d-secure

We're creating an application that will receive payments through bank cards / credit cards that enforces 3D secure while paying, and its known issue is to require Webview in the app. What bothers me is that, from what I've read, the Webview is not a maximum-security component when Javascript is enabled, and in order to pay with the 3D Secure page from the banks, it must be enabled. But I am not sure about how to actually protect the user's information when it comes to an open Webview, because javascript code integration becomes possible and (maybe) MIMA (Man in the middle attack) can be done to steal information about the card / account.

What are the ways to protect the user from not stealing the sensitive information? Any help is appreciated, thanks.